# Fragments usage

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've faced with a question if it's necessary to rewrite my application for using Fragments API. The application contains only Activities, every of which is responsible for one screen only and will not contain two ore more fragments on one screen as in the SDK example. Should I rewrite the application to Fragments API?
In the case if I must rewrite, could you please tell me which structure should be used in the project:

- Each Activity will contain one Fragment and manage it.
- There is only one activity and all the other Activities should be rewritten to Fragments.

In general it`s not clear when the Fragment should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it necessary to rewrite my application with `Fragments`?

Implementing `Fragment`s in this case is just extra work. If you can get the effect you want using only `Activity`s, that's perfectly fine.

That said, implementing your application using `Fragment`s even when its not necessary isn't always a bad idea, as it makes transitioning to multiscreen layouts quite simple. If you can see yourself optimizing for tablets at some point in the future, implementing your UIs with `Fragment`s might be a good idea.

Comment: If I decide to optimize for Tablets which structure should I use in my application?

Comment: The first one... the `Fragment`s would contain most of the UI... this would allow you to create multiscreen layouts using those `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from the following link:

> Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11), primarily to support more dynamic and flexible UI designs on large screens, such as tablets. Because a tablet's screen is much larger than that of a handset, there's more room to combine and interchange UI components. Fragments allow such designs without the need for you to manage complex changes to the view hierarchy.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

It doesn't sound like your app design necessitates the use of fragments. Here is an example of UI design that fragments were intended:

[image]

Hope this helps!